# fetch value into td tag with php and pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

with this code I get inside the td-tag the text "Array" showing up. How can I get the real value?

```
<tbody>
        <tr>
        <?php
        $STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM customers");
        $STH->execute();
        $result = $STH->fetchall();

        foreach($result as $key => $value) {
            echo "<td>$value</td>";
        }

        ?>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: loop through $value, it seems it's still an.. array ?!

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach($result as $key => $value) {
    echo "<td>{$value['field_name']}</td>";
}
```

Here `$value` is an array because `$result` should be a two dimensional array. So you need to call like this.

```
echo "<td>{$value['field_name']}</td>";
```

You can add an extra `foreach`.

```
foreach($result as $key => $inner_arr) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($inner_arr as $field_name => $field_value) {
        echo "<td>{$field_value}</td>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: is it possible to do it without "field_name"? the problem is the columns/fieldnames are dynamic. there can be 5 columns/fieldnames but there can also be 500 fieldnamens.

Comment: same solution as Mr. Martin Kleins answer. but printing duplicates (see my comment on his answer)

Comment: with your code, i get the rows but every field is twice shown up. normally it should look like: <id><name><address><email> - but now it looks like: <id><id><name><name><address><address><email><email>

Comment: Print your result array. using `print_r($result)` and update question.

Answer (score 0):

You need an extra layer

```
<tbody>

        <?php
        $STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM customers");
        $STH->execute();
        $result = $STH->fetchall();

        foreach($result as $key => $value) {
            echo '<tr>'; // as we have more rows
            // here key is a rownumber value is the full row
            //echo "<td>$value</td>";
            foreach($value as $name => $data) {
              echo "<td>$data</td>";
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }

        ?>

</tbody>
```

Comment: well done. i get the rows but every field is twice shown up. normally it should look like: <id><name><address><email> - but now it looks like: <id><id><name><name><address><address><email><email>